# The image alignment doesn't work with .rst in github

Tags: image, github, restructuredtext

I have an image that I want to align in README.rst file in github but giving the specs :

```
.. image:: Logo/PNG/respawn-logo.png
   :height: 109 px
   :width: 126 px
   :scale: 50 %
   :alt: respawn
   :align: center
```

doesn't work with the image still being at its original position and not scaling. Any reason why ?

[image]

Comment: Did you find an way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no extra options in markdown that GItHub respects for images. Only options are to:

- Resize the image yourself and link to that
- convert to an HTML img tag: [How to I change the size of an image in Github/Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534560/how-to-i-change-the-size-of-an-image-in-github-markdown)