# How to I change the size of an image in Github/Markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I'm editing a Readme.md file in a Github repository and have inserted a picture (see https://github.com/khpeek/FMCW-radar). The picture takes up the full width but is rather grainy that way, and I would prefer to make it smaller. Is there any way to do that?

P.S. I've tried the commands on
[How to change image size Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown), but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must downsize the image in an image editor. You can't change image size on GitHub's flavor of markdown.

Also: [The image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khpeek/FMCW-radar/master/Images/FMCW_schematic_SPIE.png) is already very grainy, it's not a result of its size changing.

Comment: This is not true anymore - see answer below

Answer (score 68):

You can change the size of an image in GitHub markdown by using the image link in an HTML `img` tag:

From this:

```sh
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/link-to-your-image.png)
```

To this:

```html
<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/link-to-your-image.png" width="200" />
```

Comment: This isn't working for me because they put a max-width="100%" style tag in there. Even if I try to override the style it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnErnest - the `max-width` style shouldn't be a problem unless you're trying to do a width greater than `100%`. Maybe you're putting `width` in a style tag which wouldn't work - you need to put `width` as an attribute like in the `To this:` line

Comment: I wanted the text to be exactly 1260px because that's what the screenshot was, but I had to workaround it by making the screenshot wider to match the screen resolution so that even when scaled up it doesn't make the text too big to see.

Comment: +1 Worked for me - on GitHub. Just don't let your fancy-pants MD editor put the `<img ....>` tag inside an HTML code fence.

Answer (score 10):

For images with links, I used this.

```
[<img src="./assets/sql.svg" width="30" />](./link/to/sql/file)
```